# How do we add each element of two lists in sequence in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

Write a Prolog predicate `seqadd/3` such that `seqadd(X,Y,Z)` succeeds when X and Y are lists of integers of the same length and
    Z is their sequence sum.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add 1st element of 1st list to 1st element of 2nd list and so on. Right?
If yes then you can use this approach below.

```
seqsum([],[],[]).
seqsum([H|T],[H1|T1],[H2|Z]):- H2 is H+H1 , seqsum(T,T1,Z).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?- seqsum([1,2,3],[4,5,6],Z).
   Z = [5,7,9]
   yes
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: you can / should make it `seqsum([], [], []).` to get rid of the extra false answer.

Comment: @WillNess if i add `seqsum([],[],[]).` i would get answer as M=[5,7,9] two times.

Comment: What we can get rid of that false using a simple cut. Thanks for helping me to get a better answer. `seqsum([X],[Y],[Z]):- Z is X+Y , ! .`

Comment: no need for no cuts. :) just *replace* your first clause with what I wrote. :)